# .NET - Migrating solution with two apps from WinForms to MAUI

Tags: c#, dependencies, maui

I try to migrate an old WinForms app to the new MAUI base. That app is referencing an old console app which contains all the logic (the first app is only the UI hull).

But when I try to build that solution, I get the following errors:

1. `error NETSDK1151: проект "..\<ProjectName>\<ProjectName>.csproj", на который указывает ссылка, является автономным исполняемым файлом.  Неавтономный исполняемый файл не может ссылаться на автономный исполняемый файл. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице https://aka.ms/netsdk1151` (not exact translation to English: `error NETSDK1151: the project "..\<ProjectName>\<ProjectName>.csproj", which the link points to, is a standalone executable file. A non-standalone executable file cannot reference an offline executable file. For more information, see the page https://aka.ms/netsdk1151`) - despite that I had exactly pointed `<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>` in the .csproj file.
2. `error : Empty ResolveFrameworkReference.RuntimePackPath while trying to read runtime components manifest. ResolvedFrameworkReference available: { Microsoft.NETCore.App, RuntimePackPath:  }`
   Who knows how to fix the solution? Maybe there is a template for multi-platform app, but without UI, or something similar?

---

**EDIT**: I have converted that console app to the .NET MAUI class library, as it is proposed in the comments, the first error has disappeared, but the second remains, and also I am now receiving the following errors stack:

> 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
> for Android profile? 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028: File name: 'System.Runtime.dll' 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
> reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line
> 245 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type) at
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:line 111 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve() at
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/TypeReference.cs:line
> 278 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionCache.Resolve(TypeReference
> typeReference) at
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionCache.cs:line
> 20 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.d__5.MoveNext()
> at
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line
> 40 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.IsSubclassOf(TypeDefinition
> type, String typeName, IMetadataResolver resolver) at
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line
> 94 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> MonoDroid.Tuner.FixAbstractMethodsStep.FixAbstractMethods(AssemblyDefinition
> assembly) 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssembliesNoShrink.RunTask() 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1426,3):
> error XALNS7028:    at
> Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() at
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line
> 17

And when I disabled building for Android (which is, of course, temporary), the app had been compiled, but during launch I had received [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8U38.png).
Who knows how to fix both situations?

Comment: What is this "old console app"? .NET Framework?

Comment: Did you try to change the old console app project output type to 'class library' (Project properties > Application > Output type) ?

Comment: To clarify: it may be worth creating a new project using class library template. Move your source files into that new project. Changes will be needed. How you use that library will be quite different from calling into a separate app. IMHO, once you figure out how to change calling code, the result will be more performant, and better for long term maintenance.

Comment: Hello everyone commented here! Sorry for the late answer (maybe by scale of this very active forum), I thought nobody would already answer, and did not see this comments. Console app is .NET Core, but created much earlier than MAUI. I cannot replace it by the class library because this app needs to be in the separate process which sometimes needs to be killed. Maybe there is a way to launch the class library in the separate process but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As @toolmakersteve said you may want to create a new project instead of simply changing the type of the existing project. The reason being the dependencies (which may not be updated then changing the project type) your errors seems to be related to missing dependencies. You can already try to create a new project and see if you can reference it with a simple test class, if it work you are good to copy all your files (good luck !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of "digging", I figured out that the app doesn't work when the ContentPage constructor contains parameters. For everyone who creates one's app on MAUI: **unlike the old UIs, in the MAUI the main form cannot be constructed with parameters!** (EDIT: it looks like it can but in much more complex way.) Also, **MAUI app cannot refer to the old EXE apps!** (You must create the new app and move the logic to it.) Maybe these conclusions are dull for somebody, but for me it was difficult to found this problem. The solution isn't still working fine, but by another reason, which is not subject of this question.